# How to get crysis 2 running

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux, winetricks

I am runnung ubuntu 12.04 64bit with nvidea gtx660 the with proprietary driver version 310 installed via additional drivers
I have tried a variety of things having no succsess 
I have got past the initial padlocked room, but everything was black I could see the objective marker, and the gui with the map thing

I would like to know the ubuntu version and bit (32 64)
 wine version and bit (32 64)
any patches
winetricks (install order) if known
install method, iso, steam, etc

this is for crysis2

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=12827

Answer (score 0):

There's a piece of software called [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) which runs on Wine and helps a lot with installing the required dependencies for software that it supports. It lists Crysis 2 under the games section, although you might need an install disc or .exe to run it (if you have the Steam version then it might not work). You could try that.

Comment: I tried PlayOnLinux in fact that piece of software is why I came back to Linux after a year of windows, I tried the installer that PlayOnLinux provides, both disc through iso and steam versions infact I am working again on installing the steam version I was hoping that someone that has got it working to play the whole game could post I will repot after this install